# automatically refresh client browser if server page has changed

Tags: html, typo3, extbase

I could not find any useful solution for my TYPO3 extension.
The extention gets new informaion about every 3 minutes. 
Right after the page on the server is changed, the browser should be trigged to refresh page, or better only the part which is embedded into a div section.
I have seen several pages on the internet, which always automatically update the page content.

Has anybody already done it?

Comment: You have maybe to write a ajax Enpoint and call it via javascript in your frontend. Because its not possible trigger via PHP something to browser. That how HTTP works.

Comment: Do you have an example for me?

Comment: Maybe try easyle that, this is a solution without javascript <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3">
And that a dafault ajax call example -> with content reload -> https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/38969/reload-refresh-table-after-event